# c++: member with reference to parent

Tags: c++, constructor, member

I am looking for a good pattern to implement the following:

```
class Outer;


class Inner
{
     Outer * m_outer;

   public:
     InitOuter(Outer * o) { m_outer = o; }
}

class Outer
{
    Inner  m_inner;

  public:
    Outer()
    {
      m_inner.InitOuter(outer);
    }
}
```

- Inner should always be created with a reference to outer
- m_outer will never be NULL
- m_outer will not change during the lifetime of `Inner`

Unfortunately, as I understand, `m_outer` can't be neither a reference nor a immutable pointer, as the following initialization is invalid:

```
Inner::Inner(Outer & o) : m_outer(o) {}
Outer::Outer() : m_inner(*this) {}
```

since at the initialization of `m_inner`, `Outer` isn't completely constructed and thus `this` is invalid (and may also change during furhter initialization).

The only alternative I found was to make the constructor of `Inner` non-public, and `Outer` a friend of `Inner`. That's a little better, but the "friend" relationship seems arbitrarily strong (since usually the inner class should encapsulate functionality).

How do you implement this?

---

Motivation: In my understanding of C++, "Outer" isn't yet constructed completely, so accessing `this` might legally trigger undefined behavior (could anyone confirm this - or even better that it's not the case?).

---

And no, I don't need Inversion Of Control here. Really, thank you, but no.
I've omitted details such as hiding copy CTor + assignment.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub Me too. But I'd pick "Inversion of Control" over "International Olympic Committee" from the google results.

Comment: erm, from my understanding of IOC, both setter injection and constructor injection are *implementations of IOC*... tough to avoid if at any point in Inner you are going to delegate some stuff to Outer...

Comment: Sorry, Johannes, (IMHO you didn't miss much ;)) I've also tried to clarify why I am asking.

Comment: as long as you don't access any members that are constructed *after* m_inner then passing *this into Inner is fine. Normally with this type of pattern, the constructor does nothing but initialize it's member with the pointer (or reference).

Answer (score 8):

```
Inner::Inner(Outer & o) : m_outer(o) {}
Outer::Outer() : m_inner(*this) {}
```

That's perfectly fine. Just do it like that. Also consider whether `Inner` could be a nested class (for something like an iterator, that could well make sense.

You haven't said anything on what you try to model. It should be noted that Outer also needs to have an own copy constructor and copy assignment operator or disable it. Otherwise a flat copy would cause major catastrophe.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `this` pointer in the initialization list generates compiler warning C4355 with Visual Studio 2008.  Based on the documentation, it is not a recommended practice to do this because you're passing a pointer to an unconstructed object to another object.  If that other object's constructor accesses any of the members or calls methods of the unconstructed object, the results are undefined.

However, in the limited scenario you've shown, you are not doing anything that would cause undefined behavior.  You are merely setting the `m_outer` variable to point to/reference the unconstructed object.  As long as you limit it to that, you can do this, providing the compiler warning isn't a show-stopper (our project has a standard that all compiler warnings are to be removed).

If this still bothers you, you could change the code like this.

```
class Outer; 

class Inner 
{ 
     const Outer & m_outer; 

   public:
     Inner(const Outer & o) : m_outer(o)
     {
     }
} 

class Outer 
{ 
    Inner * m_inner; 

  public: 
    Outer() 
    { 
        m_inner = new Inner(*this);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sensible modifications might be to derive outer from something like boost::noncopyable, or implement a copy constructor and assignment operator and to use std::auto_ptr for m_inner.

Comment: Yeah, agreed.  This is definitely a bare bones implementation for demonstration purposes only.

Comment: " providing the compiler warning isn't a show-stopper (our project has a standard that all compiler warnings are to be removed) "   Just add a #pragma warning( disable:.. )  !